# CSS only dynamic DIV widths ie. more DIVs per row if browser width allows

Tags: html, css, list, layout

I'm making a layout to display blocks of content side-by-side in a way where the browser window is filled 100% with DIV blocks

I remember seeing a CSS only method that adjusts the width of DIVs depending on the browser window. If space allows, 3 DIVs are displayed, if you decrease the width of the browser, it will change to 2 DIVs per row, pushing the 3rd down, while keeping the DIVs at an ideal width always filling the window.

I've been trying to recreate this

Say I need a min-width of 500px. If there is 1000px available, it would show 2 blocks per row. If 1500px, 3 blocks per row, and so on. But based on how many blocks can fit, I need the width of each block was dynamic so as to keep the browser window filled.

Ive seen this done before exactly. I remember even with javascript disabled the effect could be seen, so I figure the answer must be CSS

Comment: Look for a responsive design.

Comment: @panther Is there any way to do this without Bootstrap? This is a perfect example: https://www.azamaraclubcruises.com/

Comment: sure, bootstrap isn't necessary. See the media-queries in CSS, eg. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries.

```css
/* Display 3 items per row for browsers with width >= 1024px */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .items {
        width: 33.33%;    
    }
}

/* Display 2 items per row for browsers with width >= 768px and width <= 1023px */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px){
    .items {
        width: 50%;    
    }
}

/* Display 1 item per row for browsers with width <= 767px */
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .items {
        width: 100%;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to achieve what you want.

Basically set the jumps where you want to skip from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3 and from 3 to 4, etc. based on window width.

And put the width in %. This way the existing items will stretch to the available width.

If you want to fit 3 in a row, use width 33%, to fit 2 use width 50% and so on.

If you can't make them to break the line, you can use [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) to force them.